# Laravel smt failed to authenticate SMTP using the following authenticators: "CRAM-MD5", "LOGIN", "PLAIN"

Tags: php, laravel, email, authentication, smtp

I am trying to setup smtp mail in laravel 9 application but I cant get it to work.

The settings I am using in online smtp tester (which is working good) are:

```
host:mail.****.**
post:587
Use secured connection: no
Use authentication: yes
login credentials...
```

in `mail.php` file:

```
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => null,//env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode'  => null,
            'verify_peer' => false,
        ],
```

and in `.env` file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.*****.**
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@******.**
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="user@*****.**"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

But when I am trying to send the email from my application I get this error:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "user@*****.**" using the following
 authenticators: "CRAM-MD5", "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "CRAM-MD5" returned 
"Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error:
 authentication failed: authentication failure".". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned 
"Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: 
authentication failed: authentication failure".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned 
"Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: 
authentication failed: authentication failure".".
```

Answer (score 3):

After some testing I figured out that if you have special characters in `Password` then you should enclose it in double quotes in `.env` file.